# Distance order of coordinates equation without acos

Tags: coordinates, distance, equation

I need an equation that will compute the distance order between 2 coordinates(the result unit doesnt matter. I want  obtain only sorted list).

The equation can include cosinus and sinus of specyfic cord, but can't acos and sin/cos of the difrence cord1-cord2.

**For example:** it can include `cos(cord1.lattitude) +sin(cord2.longitude)` but cant `sin(cord1.lattitude-cord2.lattitude)`.

Someone told me that such of that equation exist but I cannot find it on the internet.

EDIT: I found the solution that includes the earth curve and gives pretty solid solution. This query gives us the Descending distance order value of two coordinates.Compute the excacly distance is not a problem when we got correct order of data:

> (sin(currentPosLattitude) * sin(targetLattitude)) +(cos(currentPositionLattitude) * cos(targetLattitude))*
>                         (sin(currentPosLongitude) * sin(targetLongittude) + cos(currentPosLongitude)*cos(targetLongittude))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Excellent question, would love to here the answer as I need to program it too.

Comment: Please look at my update: I edited how I handle it